# Upload File data into database using spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to upload data into 2 database tables(factory and factoryType) using the below form but it isnt working can somebody take a look :

```
Factory table:factoryId,factoryname
FactoryType table: factoryType,factoryTypeId
FactoryConf table: factoryID,factoryTypeId
```

We are using hibernate for the database operations.

**Model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FactoryConf", uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "factoryId" } )
})
public class FactoryConf {

    @Id
    long factoryId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "factoryId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Factory factory;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "factoryTypeId")
    FactoryType factoryType;

    public FactoryConf() {
        super();
    }

    public FactoryConf(long factoryId, FactoryType factoryType) {
        super();
        this.factoryType = factoryType;
        this.factoryId = factoryId;
    }

    public Factory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void setFactory(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public FactoryType getFactoryType() {
        return factoryType;
    }

    public void setFactoryType(FactoryType factoryType) {
        this.factoryType = factoryType;
    }

    public long getFactoryId() {
        return factoryId;
    }

    public void setFactoryId(long factoryId) {
        this.factoryId = factoryId;
    }

    public FactoryType getFactoryTypeByFactoryID(long factoryId){
        return factoryType;
    }
}
```

**Bean class:**

```
/**
 * This bean is defined to parse each record from the CSV file. 
 * All records are mapped to instances of this bean class.
 * 
 */
public class FactoryCSVFileInputBean {
    private String upload_id;
    private String file_name;
    private byte file_data;
    private long Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Type;

//getter setters    
}
```

**CSV parsing:**

```
/**
 * This class is defined for following actions
 * 1. Validate the input CSV file format, header columns.
 * 2. Parse the CSV file into a list of beans.
 * 3. Validate input records with missing data and prepare a valid factory list to be processed. *
 */
public class FactoryCSVUtil {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FactoryCSVUtil.class);
    private static final List<String> fileHeaderFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final String UTF8CHARSET = "UTF-8";
    static{
        for (Field f : FactoryCSVFileInputBean.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            fileHeaderFields.add(f.getName());
        }             
    }

    public static List<FactoryCSVFileInputBean> getCSVInputList(InputStream inputStream){
        CSVReader reader = null;
        List<FactoryCSVFileInputBean> csvList = null;
        FactoryCSVFileInputBean inputRecord = null;
        String[] header = null;        
        String[] row = null;

        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,UTF8CHARSET));
            csvList = new ArrayList<FactoryCSVFileInputBean>();
            header = reader.readNext();
            boolean isEmptyLine = true;
            while ((row = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                isEmptyLine = true;
                if(!(row.length==1 && StringUtils.isBlank(row[0]))){//not an empty line, not even containing ','
                    inputRecord = new FactoryCSVFileInputBean();
                    isEmptyLine = populateFields(inputRecord, header, row);    
                    if(row.length != header.length)
                        //inputRecord.setUploadStatus("Not Loaded - Missing or invalid Data");

                    if(!isEmptyLine)
                        csvList.add(inputRecord);
                }
            }                       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug("IOException while accessing FactoryCSVFileInputBean: " + e);
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            log.debug("IllegalAccessException while accessing FactoryCSVFileInputBean: " + e);
            return null;
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            log.debug("InvocationTargetException while copying FactoryCSVFileInputBean properties: " + e);
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Exception while parsing CSV file: " + e);
            return null;
        }finally{
            try{
                if(reader!=null)
                    reader.close(); 
            }catch(IOException ioe){}
        }

        return csvList;
    }


    protected static boolean populateFields(FactoryCSVFileInputBean inputRecord,String[] header, String[] row) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        boolean isEmptyLine = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            String val = row[i];

            if(!StringUtils.isBlank(val)){
                BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().copyProperty(inputRecord, header[i], val);
                isEmptyLine = false;
            } else {
                //inputRecord.setUploadStatus(String.format("Not Loaded - Missing or invalid Data for:%s",header[i]));
            }
        }

        return isEmptyLine;
    }


    public static void validateInputFile(CommonsMultipartFile csvFile, Model model){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        CSVReader reader = null;
        String fileName = csvFile.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        if(fileExtension.toUpperCase().equals("CSV")){
            try{
                inputStream = csvFile.getInputStream();
                reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,UTF8CHARSET));
                String[] header = reader.readNext();
                if(header!=null){
                    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
                        if(!header[i].equals("") && !fileHeaderFields.contains(header[i])){
                            log.debug("Invalid Column found in upload file: " + header[i]);   
                            model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Invalid Column found in upload file: " + header[i]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    for(csvHeaderFieldsEnum field : csvHeaderFieldsEnum.values()){
                        if(!Arrays.asList(header).contains(field.getValue())){                           
                            log.debug("Missing column in upload file: " + field.getValue());
                            model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Missing column in upload file: " + field.getValue());  
                            break;
                        }                        
                    }   

                }else{
                    model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "File is Empty - Please select a valid file");                   
                }                
                String[] data = reader.readNext();
                if(data==null){
                    log.debug("Empty file with header - No data found");
                    model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Empty file with header - No data found");
                }                           
            }catch(IOException e){
                log.debug("IOException in reading the CSV file: " + e);
                model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Exception in reading the CSV file");
            }finally{
                if(reader!=null) 
                    try{
                        reader.close();     
                    }catch(IOException e){ log.debug("IOException in closing reader of CSV file: " + e);}
            }
        }
        else{
            model.addAttribute("failureMsg", "Invalid file format - Please select a CSV file");
        }       

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class FactoryUploadForm {
    private CommonsMultipartFile fileData;
    private String uploadComment;
    /**
     * @return the fileData
     */
    public CommonsMultipartFile getFileData() {
        return fileData;
    }
    /**
     * @param fileData the fileData to set
     */
    public void setFileData(CommonsMultipartFile fileData) {
        this.fileData = fileData;
    }
    /**
     * @return the uploadComment
     */
    public String getUploadComment() {
        return uploadComment;
    }
    /**
     * @param uploadComment the uploadComment to set
     */
    public void setUploadComment(String uploadComment) {
        this.uploadComment = uploadComment;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return " CSVFileName: " + getFileData().getOriginalFilename() + "; Upload Comment: " + uploadComment;
    }


}
```

**Controller**

@Controller
public class FactoryUploadDownloadController {

```
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(FactoryUploadDownloadController.class);

@Resource
Service Service;

@Resource
FactoryUploadRepository repository;


@RequestMapping(value = "/submitUploadFactoryForm")
public String uploadFactory(FactoryUploadForm uploadform,
        HttpServletRequest request, Model model, BindingResult result) {
    logger.debug("====================================================================");

    List<FactoryCSVFileInputBean> csvList = null;
    List<FactoryType> factoryTypes = Service.getFactoryTypes();

    try {
        CommonsMultipartFile file = uploadform.getFileData();
        // parse csv file to list
        csvList = FactoryCSVUtil.getCSVInputList(file.getInputStream());
        if (csvList == null) {
            model.addAttribute("failureMsg","Error in file parsing - Please verify the file");

            logger.debug("---------------------------------------------------------");
            return "sucess";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("sorry this isn't working for you");

    }
    try {
        CommonsMultipartFile file = uploadform.getFileData();

        for (FactoryCSVFileInputBean inputRecord : csvList) {
            Factory factoryentity = new Factory();
            factoryentity.setId(inputRecord.getId());
            factoryentity.setName(inputRecord.getName());
            factoryentity = this.Service.saveFactory(factoryentity);

            FactoryConf factoryconf = new FactoryConf();
            factoryconf.setFactory(factoryentity);
            factoryconf.setFactoryType(pickFactoryType(factoryTypes,inputRecord.getType()));
            model.addAttribute("factoryconf", factoryconf);

            this.Service.savefactoryCfg(factoryconf);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("sorry this isnt working for you");

    }
    return "success";
}

private FactoryType pickFactoryType(List<FactoryType> types, String typeName) {

    for (FactoryType type : types) {
        if (type.getFactoryType().equalsIgnoreCase(typeName))
            return type;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Factory Type Invalid :%s", typeName));
}
```

}

Comment: "but it isnt working" - care to elaborate? Do you have a stack-trace?

Comment: Also, you don't need to define a `@UniqueConstraint` for an `@Id` field. They are already unique by definition. And if the table name is the same name as your Entity, you don't even need the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: Where are you saving the Entities to the database? I can see that the static `getCSVInputList` method parses your CSV and returns it, but what takes that list and saves it to Entities?

Comment: Hi Duncan, apologies for the confusion by isnt working i mean I am stuck at reading the multipart form data and putting it in database tables In the controller.Please excuse my english.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, I understand that you are not able to parse data from a CSV file. [Here](https://ariestania.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/how-to-upload-and-read-csv-file-on-springmvc-using-opencsv/) is sample code for similar task. I think it should help.